# JScrollPane not appearing?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane

Why is my JScrollPane not showing up? if I do it with the table (commented part) it works fine, but when I put it into a scrollpane ( I need too, the data base is really long) it never appears, can anyone help me? :o)

Here's the code:

```
 JButton btnRefresh = new JButton("Refresh");
    btnRefresh.setBounds(130, 35, 80, 30);
    btnRefresh.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try{

                ResultSet r = s.executeQuery("Select * From "+comboBox.getSelectedItem());
                int rows = 0;
                while ( r.next ( ) ) rows++;
                r.first();
                int cols =  r.getMetaData().getColumnCount();


                String columnNames[ ] = new String [ cols ];
                for ( int i = 0; i < columnNames.length; i++ )
                    columnNames [ i ] = r.getMetaData().getColumnName(i + 1);

                for ( int i = 0; i < columnNames.length; i ++ )
                    System.out.print( columnNames[i] + " " );

                r.first();
                int i = 1;
                while(r.next()){
                    for ( int j = 0; j < cols; j++ ){
                        rowData[i][j] = r.getString(j+1);
                    }
                    i++;
                }


                table = new JTable( rowData, columnNames);
                //table.setBounds ( 10, 95, 770, 560 );

                scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
                //browserPanel.add( table);
                browserPanel.add(scrollPane);

                //table.repaint();
                scrollPane.repaint();
                //table.setVisible(true);
                scrollPane.setVisible( true );

                browserPanel.revalidate();
                browserPanel.repaint();

            }
            catch(Exception x){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Not Found");
                x.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    browserPanel.add(btnRefresh);
```

Comment: It is typically easier to have the table and scroll pane added at start-up.  Then when the DB access is complete, set a new model with the `ResultSet`.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: *"here's the real link"*  To a screenshot of the same code snippet above?  I'm so glad you could not include it!

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
browserPanel.add(scrollPane);
```

If `browserPanel` has already been displayed then you should call [revalidate()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#revalidate%28%29) method after adding the scroll pane, like this:

```
browserPanel.add(scrollPane);
browserPanel.revalidate();
browserPanel.repaint();
```

From [Container.add()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add%28java.awt.Component%29) javadoc:

> This method changes layout-related information, and therefore,
>   invalidates the component hierarchy. **If the container has already been
>   displayed, the hierarchy must be validated thereafter in order to
>   display the added component.**

Some other tips:

- As @Andrew says It is typically easier to have the table and scroll pane added at start-up. Then when the DB access is complete, set a new model with the `ResultSet`
- Swing components must be created and updated in the [Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).
- If you are actually doing so then you should avoid make database calls in the EDT. These should be done in a separate thread using, for instance, a [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) which ensures heavy tasks are made in a separate thread and GUI updates are performed in the EDT.